# Selected from select option HTML suddenly disappear

Tags: html

This is the strangest thing that happens to me
when the first load, the selected from the field is appear, but after a sec then suddenly disappear.

It's only an ordinary HTML select option but IDK what is causing this, I've checked on CSS and there is no weird colliding CSS...

I put only simple HTML code like this:

```html
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Here is the video to show you what really happens
[Strange selected select option](https://youtu.be/N-6a6E3cmo4)

Comment: Is the select inside a form?

Comment: nope.. it's outside

Comment: do you guys think this is causing by JS or CSS? i can't understand what really happen

Comment: Check if there is code on onload, to clear or reset controls.

Comment: THANKS @NicolasI you saved my life
there is onload JS code, render on another file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake, there is onload JS code rendered on another file

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('input[type="text"], textarea, select').val('');
}
```

This code is meant to clear the text area field when the page is reload
but seems i can't use this code because it's colliding with the select option